# How to catch a match a certain part of a string in R

Tags: r, match

I have used seqinr package  to read a certain fasta file with some genes in it. Now each gene has got attributes that give me a a line like this :

```
> getAnnot(g[1])

">Translation:ENSANGP00000020176 Database:core Gene:ENSANGG00000017687 Clone:AAAB01008888 Contig:AAAB01008888_84 Chr:2R Basepair:42989807 Status:known"
```

I want to get the result to be Gene:ENSANGG00000017687

Thanks
here is my code

```
##rm(list=ls())
library(seqinr)
g<-seqinr::read.fasta('frthomas.fasta')
g2<-getAnnot(g[1:500])
```

Comment: I commented out `rm(list = ls())`. Not a good idea to include that in case someone doesn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `regexec` here. For example if your string is stored in `a`

```
sapply(regmatches(a, regexec("Gene:(\\w+)\\b",a)), `[`, 2)
[1] "ENSANGG00000017687"
```

Here we take the second element in the list to just get the gene value. If you wanted the "Gene:" part as well, change the 2 to a 1.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, this answer seems to be also what I am looking to do. However, I can not quite apply "Gene:(\\w+)\\b" to parse out what I am looking for in my character string. Could you please explain that element of your answer in more detail? My string looks like "mgm4577492.3|D00420:57:HAA5HADXX:1:1111:9119:79755" and I would like to parse out "4577492"

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result is in the third element after we split the string at every space with `strsplit`

```
> string <-  
    ">Translation:ENSANGP00000020176 Database:core Gene:ENSANGG00000017687 Clone:AAAB01008888 Contig:AAAB01008888_84 Chr:2R Basepair:42989807 Status:known"
> unlist(strsplit(string, " "))[3]
# [1] "Gene:ENSANGG00000017687"
```